# GridView items not showing up fully in Android

Tags: android, gridview

All GridView Items aren't showing up until I give the height for the layout.

The same settings in a differnt xml works fine.

How will I make it to show all items without giving the height.

It always shows only two items.

Please see below what i had done :

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/gridOptionsView"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/OptionsGrid"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:columnWidth="125dp"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
                    android:numColumns="2"
                    android:visibility="visible">
                </GridView>

            </LinearLayout>
```

I have different Linearlayouts in the XML one of them is shown above.

I am not able to track the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Add screenshot so that everyone can understand your problem better.

Comment: I don't get what are you trying to say, `layout_height` is always **required** for the elements in a xml layout...How is possible that your app run without having set `layout_height`?

Comment: the issue you face is not clear, as @g2o said, layout_height is definitely required, please add details to explain the issue better

Comment: @g2o: By saying setting layout height means hardcoded height like 100dp . instead of wrap_content or match_parent

Comment: Try giving linear layout match_parent and gridview wrap_content, if u have more than one linear layout , give them layout_weight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

Your source code LinearLayout is the main container layout so this layout change this statement

**android:layout_height="wrap_content"** to  **android:layout_height="match_parent"**

so but when you set your gridview height to match_parent. The parent layout   Layout_height is wrap_content. So that reason your gridview will not be display in full display. change done in below code

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gridOptionsView"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/OptionsGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="125dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:visibility="visible">
    </GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `LinearLayout` is the parent layout.

```
<LinearLayout>
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
</LinearLayout>
```

when you set your `GridView` height to `match_parent`.

The parent layout here is `LinearLayout` and its `layout_height` is `wrap_content`. So your `GridView` will not be displayed in full display height.

Do this instead.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gridOptionsView"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/OptionsGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="125dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:visibility="visible">
    </GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `GridView` height from

`android:layout_height="match_parent"`

to

`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`